# Having trouble with getting Objects after loading JSON to canvas - Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am building a template tool with `Fabric.JS`. I have been able to successful serialize a canvas into `DatalessJSON`, and then deserialize the `DatalessJSON` back onto the canvas. However, I am having an issue trying to work with the objects once the `JSON` has been loaded.

```
 function loadTemplate() {


 var template = $('#JSONserial').val();
 canvas.clear();
 canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(template);
 canvas.renderAll();

 var allObjects = canvas.getObjects();

 console.log(allObjects);
```

So here, The canvas is definitely loaded with the `JSON` successfully, and all of the objects appear no problem. However, when I try the `getObjects` function, the `console.log` statement returns `"[]"`

I have extended the `toObjects` function with the `'name'` attribute so that I can identify each of the `JSON` loaded objects, but I can't even get that far as I am unable to pull the objects at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I figured this out. So there seems to just be slight time after loading the objects that they are not available to call. I put the 'getObjects()' function  inside a timeout function with a timeout of 100, and it seems to be working now.

Comment: that is the wrong way. check the answer

Answer (score 0):

loadFromDatalessJson is asyncronous.

```
loadFromDatalessJSON(json, callback, reviver)
```

Use the callback to run code at the end of object loading.

```
 function loadTemplate() {
 var template = $('#JSONserial').val();
 canvas.clear();
 var allObjects = [];
 canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(template, function(){
   allObjects = canvas.getObjects();
   console.log(allObjects);
   canvas.renderAll();
 });

}
```